# Thread won't output stream until it is terminated

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to print the live output from running an external jar, it runs in a thread and the jar does get executed, the problem is that the output doesnt print until the thread is terminated.

```
public void run() {
    Process proc = null;
    try {

        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar A.jar");    
        InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        BufferedInputStream bes = new BufferedInputStream(err);

        String iss = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF8");
        String ess = IOUtils.toString(err, "UTF8");

        System.out.println(iss);
        System.out.println(ess);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        this.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need separate Threads to read both Streams while the process is executed.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp Thank you! I'll give that a try.

Comment: In this case you also don't want to use `IOUtils.toString()` as is it only returns after the stream is at the end.

Comment: Also, `IOUtils.toString()` blocks until the stream is over. I think you need to ditch `IOUtils.toString()`, and maybe even `BufferedInputStream`, and use InputStream directly.

Comment: Also, the `this.interrupt()` is confusing and probably not problem-related. You might want to remove those details to create a minimal example.

Comment: Okay, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run them both in separate threads, in order to read them simultaneously.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/martin/test.py");
        InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();

        Thread tIn = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    int ch;
                    ch = in.read();
                    if (ch < 0)
                        break;
                    System.out.print((char) ch);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Thread tErr = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    int ch;
                    ch = err.read();
                    if (ch < 0)
                        break;
                    System.err.print((char) ch);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        tIn.start();
        tErr.start();

        try {
            tIn.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            tErr.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // this.interrupt();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // this.interrupt();
    }
}
```

That is the quick-and-dirty version in a single function. Of course, it would be preferable to write a class that wraps that functionality.